# Probabilistic Hough transform in OpenCV 2.4.9 (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

My question is about Hough transform in OpenCV 2.4.9 (Python).

Here is an extract from tutorial:

cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]]) → lines

I do not really understand what "lines[," means. I use the function in the following manner:

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 25, 2,25,115)

But what does parameter "2" here really mean? Seems nothing change when I assign different values for that parameter.

Tnanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use it like this

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edge_image, rho=1.0, theta=math.pi/180.0,
                                    threshold=thresholdVal,
                                    minLineLength=minlinelengthVal,
                                    maxLineGap=maxlinegapVal)
```

If you read up about [Hough Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Implementation) and probabilistic hough transforms, you'd realize that an accumulator is used to accumulate all the edge points. `rho` is the distance resolution of the accumulator in pixels and `theta` is the angle resolution of the accumulator in radians.

And as far as `cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]]) → lines` docs is concerned, it is sort of function overloading but since python provides optional arguments, this is used. `lines[` just means that you can pass a numpy array where the lines will be stored. So now, if you want pass other parameters and skip `lines`, you'd have to pass them by the parameter name.